# Accelerometer Gyroscope and Magnetometer to Drift Angle calculate

Tags: magnetometer, drift, mpu

I have one ICU is ICM20498 9 Axis Breakout board.

I am able to Derive some co-ordinate using this Sensor to Accelerate X,Y and Z also Gyro X,Y and Z and Magnetometer X,Y and Z i have verified this all the axis coordinates are well Calibrated.

So, i am trying to find Drift Angle using this All parameter is there any idea how can i derive this drift angle my basically application to found drift angle in scate board.

I have used Sparkfun library for this Sensor raw value also i have tried another some library those developed by the Adafrut and some person so i am not able to drive drift Angle if you have any idea it well help me a lot.

Thanks

I have try to drive roll pitch and yaw value to use kelmen filter and try to drive one heading angle but not able to get this angle to drift angle